# No Overload for method matches delegate with Nancyfx

Tags: c#, asynchronous, routes, nancy

I have a function that's called from a Nancy route,  which works fine with a route parameter and a cancel token parameter, but I would like to add a third parameter but I get an error (Error  CS0123  No overload for 'PostAsync' matches delegate 'Func>'). Here is my code:

**The definition**

```
Task<dynamic> PostAsync(dynamic parameter, string payload, CancellationToken cancel)
```

**The actual function**

```
private async Task<dynamic> PostAsync(dynamic parameter, string payload, CancellationToken cancel)
```

**Nancy route**

```
Post ["/{route*}" ,"{payload}",true] = PostAsync
```

Comment: Please, add which nancy version you are using and add the class definition where you notice the error.